# Sorting on Multiple Fields

Tags: nest

Does Nest support sorting on multiple fields? For example, say I want to sort first by FieldA ascending and then by FieldB descending.

My current approach looks something like this:

```
searchDescriptor.Sort(s =>s.OnField("FieldA").Ascending().OnField("FieldB").Descending());
```

But the "FieldB".Descending() part seems to be the only sort option that is sent to elasticsearch.

Does anyone know if there is another way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are adding multiple fields on the same sort descriptor, which is overriding the previous value.  Instead, you need to specify a new sort descriptor for each field:

```
searchDescriptor
    .Sort(s => s
        .OnField("FieldA")
        .Ascending()
    )
    .Sort(s => s
        .OnField("FieldB")
        .Descending()
    )
```

Comment: This no longer works. Multiple .Sort(...) would lead to the last one overwriting all the previous sort commands.

Comment: the answer below should be marked as correct answer

Comment: Tried with Elastic server 2.4.6 and Nest 2.5.8 here, this compiles but does not work. The answer from @MagnusO. below works and should be accepted instead.

Answer (score 11):

I recent version of Nest the correct way of sortin on multiple fileds would be:

```
.Sort(s => s
    Field(f => f
        .Field("FieldA")
        .Order(SortOrder.Ascending)
    )
    .Field(f => f
        .Field("FieldB")
        .Order(SortOrder.Ascending)
    )
);
```

Comment: I have the latest version of ES Nest and I'm writing the exact same code as you have in this example but it isn't working; it is only applying the last sort (FieldB in your example).  Please let me know if there is anything else to get it to work.

Comment: Edit: this appears to be working if you specify simple fields ("FieldA" and "FieldB" in your example) but not if you are using a function as one of  your sorts (even though the same function works if used by itself as the only sort function).

Comment: .Sort(
      sort => sort
       .Field(i => i
        .Field(ii => ii.Year == 0)
        .Order(SortOrder.Descending)
       )
     )
     .Sort(sort=> sort
      .Ascending(f => f.Year)
     )

Comment: Test this: ..Sort(sort => sort
 .Field(i => i
  .Field(ii => ii.Year == 0)
  .Order(SortOrder.Descending)
 )
 .Field(i => i
  .Field(ii => ii.Year)
  .Order(SortOrder.Ascending)
 )
)

Answer (score 4):

for sorting on multiple dynamic fields, SortDescriptor can be useful.

```
        var sortDescriptor = new SortDescriptor<{YourType}>();

        sortDescriptor.Field(f => f.YourFieldName, Nest.SortOrder.Ascending);

        // If Field Name is Dynamic
        sortDescriptor.Field(
            "someOtherFieldName",
            Nest.SortOrder.Descending);         

        var searchResponse = await client.SearchAsync<{YourType}>(x => x
        .Query(y => query)
        .Sort(s => sortDescriptor)
        .From(from)
        .Size(size)
        );
```

Answer (score 2):

```
searchDescriptor
    .Sort(s => s
          .Ascending(a => a.OrgId)
          .Descending(d => d.CreateTimeInUtc)
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

The following works in NEST 7.12:

```
new SortDescriptor<Subject>()
    .Ascending(f => f.CurrentRunStarted)
    .Ascending(f => f.LastRunDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like this. You also can use the names from your model.

```
   EsClient.Search<Business>(s => s
      .Query (qq=> {...})
      .Sort(sort => sort.OnField(s => s.Name).Descending())
      .Sort(sort => sort.OnField(s => s.Age).Descending())
    )
```